# When to use with(nolock) and WITH (XLOCK, ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCK)

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

What is difference between with(nolock) and WITH (XLOCK, ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCK).

In My application, I was processing 10000 data using parallel.Foreach library but many times duplicate records inserted.To handel this situation I used 
WITH (XLOCK, ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCK) and that will worked for me.

but I am confused, In which situation I need to use with(nolock) and WITH (XLOCK, ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCK).

Comment: Typically *never*. If you think you need them, there's a problem with the code. 10K lines is essentially nothing. If your statement is slow, you should fix *it*. By using Parallel.Foreach you are probably making things much worse - instead of processing data in a single connection, you have competing connections and contention, multiple roundtrips instead of one etc.

Comment: *What* are you trying to do? Why don't you use SSIS or a SQL statement? Did you check the execution plan of the queries? Do you have the proper indexes? Any delays should appear at the 100K-rows level, not at 10K. That practically fits in the server cache

Comment: Besides, the multiple locks *didn't* fix your duplicates problem, they *prevented* parallel execution and essentially negated `Parallel.ForEach`. I'd bet the final result is slower than if you only used a single connection